# How to extend from an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object.

```
const ab = {
  method: function() {
  },
  method1 : function () {
  }
}
```

I want to build a class which would have all the functions in above object as static methods.

So that if i do something like

```
Class Me extends ab;
```

that should be equivalent to

```
Class Me {
  static method() {}
  static method1() {}
}
```

Any comments on this?

Given object `ab` is unknown to me (accepted as input and i need to return the class), how can i achieve the same?

I don't want to use traditional `function` based static methods.

Comment: How about `Me = Object.assign({}, ab)` (if you want to use it like `Me.method()`, etc.)

Comment: I would like to accept this as answer. Would you please put an answer for all of us?

Comment: Well a class can only extend another class. Objects and Classes are not the same even if they do look so.

Comment: @codeofnode Sure, just let me prepare an example. )

Comment: @raina77ow: if you assign to an empty object, it won't act like a class. Reflected that in my answer.

Comment: @WiktorZychla what i meant from @raina77ow  is `Object.assign(Me, ab)`

Comment: @WiktorZychla i do appreciate your answer as well. If i use `Object.assign(Me, ab)` that has added advantage of if i already have some other methods with `Me` and i want to extend on top of those methods. So readability and class love is not compromised.

Comment: Added as an answer, comments/questions are welcome. ) Honestly speaking, I'm a bit doubtful about practicality of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is using so-called [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_expressions) as a parameter of Object.assign. For example:

```js
const _extra = {
  doSomethingExtra: function() {
    console.log('doSomethingExtra');
  }
};

class Base {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething with ' + this.value);
  }
}

const Extra = Object.assign(class Extra extends Base {}, _extra);
const extra = new Extra(42);
extra.doSomething();
console.log(extra.constructor.name);  // Extra
Extra.doSomethingExtra();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you just create a new object that has given object in its prototype chain. An easiest way when working on bare objects would be

```js
const ab = {
  method: function() {
    return 1;
  },
  method1 : function () {
  }
}

const ac = Object.create(ab);

console.log(ab.method());
console.log(ac.method());
```

The newly created `ac` object acts like the *class with static methods* you ask for.

A benefit from setting up an explicit proto chain is that members you modify later in `ab` will be reflected in `ac`.

**Edit:** as pointed out in comments, if you want a class (which will act like a constructor function) you need a function with properties copied from the source object:

```js
const ab = {
      method: function() {
        return 1;
      },
      method1 : function () {
      }
}

function Me() {}
// dummy member to show that Me is a class
Me.prototype.foo = function() { return 2; } 

// assign static methods
Object.assign(Me, ab);

// Me is a class
var m = new Me();
console.log( m.foo() );

// but has static methods
console.log( Me.method() );
```

Comment: But he needs a CLASS. Class and Objects are not exactly the same even if they are often mixed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ab = {
  method: function() {
  },
  method1 : function () {
  }
};

function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype = Object.assign({}, ab); 

/* Instantiate the class. */
var alice = new Person('Alice', 93);
var bill = new Person('Bill', 30);
```

Comment: This way `me` is just an object, it doesn't act like a class.

Answer (score 0):

Using the trick in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809342/1503495

This on liner seems perfect for me.

`Object.assgin(Me, ab);`

Added advantage of this is, if i already have some other methods with `Me` and i want to extend on top of those methods. So readability and class love is not compromised.